# Sliding panel in jquery mobile [data-role="panel"]

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-mobile

I've created sliding panel using jquery mobile , i want decrease the width size of the panel , i dont know how to do it?! I googled alot but didnt find correct one 
my code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" class="jqm-demos ui-responsive-panel" data-title="Home">
    <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="true" class="ui-responsive-panel">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="contentLink">Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="#home" class="contentLink">My profile </a></li>
                <li><a href="#home" class="contentLink">My Score </a></li>
                <li><a href="#home" class="contentLink">Ask Questions </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <a href="#myPanel" data-role="button" data-display="reveal" data-position="right" data-icon="gear" data-reveal="reveal" data-dismissible="true">Menu</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with css:

```
.ui-responsive-panel{
   width: 200px; /* <---------your choice of px*/
}
```

with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $('#myPanel').css('width','200px');
});
```

or this:

```
   $('#myPanel').width(200);
```

Your comment: *`i want decrease the width size of the panel`* try below one:

```
$(function(){
   $('#myPanel').css('width',$(this).width()-200+'px');
});
```

Comment: but it come like this ... 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7s0BYiHsMBtUWlGcG1jZWY0cm8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: could you plz tell what is current width of the panel.

Comment: i gave width:200px look at this. how to do i decrease those gap, please help me..  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7s0BYiHsMBtdHQzVDR0ekt5MVU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if you could post a fiddle that would be better to rectify the issue but i Think `margin padding` or `positioning` issue is there.

Comment: thanks.. i got it.. look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/shreeramns/Lzs4b/2/
left:0;
right:0;margin-left:-70px;